# Found an error "one or more indexers are invalid. make sure your magento cron job is running."?

Tags: magento2

When I run below code in command prompt:

> C:\xampp\php>php C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento indexer:reindex

it is showing as access denied.

Answer (score 0):

Reindex in magento 2, go to the CLI and then the root folder of your magento installation and run the below command:

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

If you use linux operating system Check your file permission